# CRM_URL Report Parameter is incorrect

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am building custom reports in Microsoft CRM and am using the CRM_URL parameter to created drill downs.

However, the URL coming in is ***http://**myserver.com/org/CRMReports...* but it should be **https://**myserver.com/org/CRMReports...

My understanding is that this value is dynamically passed in by MS CRM.  How/where can I update this URL to use https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my issue was #4 & #5 from this link:

http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/op/articles/secure_comm.aspx#ID0EFD

> For deployments that will not be used
>   by external clients, which connect
>   over the Internet, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Obtain a certificate from a CA. To use certificates you will have set
>      up a public key infrastructure (PKI),
>      which consists of one or more CAs that
>      are linked in a hierarchy. These CAs
>      and the PKI are required to manage
>      certificate issuance, validation,
>      renewal, and revocation in one or more
>      organizations. You can use a
>      third-party PKI with Microsoft Windows
>      Server 2003, or you can establish your
>      own PKI, based on Windows Server 2003
>      Certificate Services.
> 2. Make sure that there are no users accessing Internet Information
>      Services (IIS) where the Microsoft
>      Dynamics CRM Web application is
>      installed. To do this, stop the
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site:
>      right-click the Web site, and then
>      click Stop.
> 3. Configure the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site to use SSL. To do this,
>      perform the following steps on the
>      server running IIS where the Microsoft
>      Dynamics CRM Web application is
>      installed:
>           1. Start Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
>           2. Right-click the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site, and then click
>      Properties.
>           3. Click the Directory Security tab, click Server
>      Certificate, and then follow the
>      instructions in the Web Server
>      Certificate Wizard.
>           4. If you want clients to only use SSL when they connect to the
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM application, on
>      the Directory Security tab in the
>      Secure communications area, click
>      Edit.
>           5. On the Secure Communications dialog box, click the
>      Require secure channel (SSL) check
>      box.
>           6. Close Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
>
>    Important: You can apply only a single certificate to the Microsoft
>      Dynamics CRM Web site. Therefore, you
>      if you have configured Microsoft
>      Dynamics CRM Server for both internal
>      and Internet-facing (external) access,
>      you cannot configure SSL for both
>      internal and external connections to
>      the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site.
> 4. You must manually modify the following values in the configuration
>      database.
>
>    Warning: Incorrectly modifying the configuration database
>      (MSCRM_CONFIG) can cause unexpected
>      behavior in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>      system or cause the system to stop
>      working. We recommend that you back up
>      the Microsoft Dynamics CRM system
>      before you complete these steps. For
>      information about how to back up the
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM system, see the
>      Operating and Maintaining Guide that
>      is part of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>      4.0 Implementation Guide document set.
>           1. On the computer running Microsoft SQL Server, start SQL Server
>      Management Studio.
>           2. Expand Databases, expand MSCRM_CONFIG, expand Tables,
>      right-click dbo.DeploymentProperties,
>      and then click Open Table.
>           3. In the dbo.DeploymentProperties table under
>      the ColumnName column, in the
>      ADRootDomainScheme row, change the
>      NVarCharColumn column value from http
>      to https. Note that this value must be
>      in lower-case letters.
>           4. In the dbo.DeploymentProperties table, under
>      the ColumnName column, in the
>      ADSdkRootDomain row, change the
>      NVarCharColumn column value by using
>      the name of the certificate configured
>      for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web
>      site. The name of the certificate can
>      be found, in Internet Information
>      Services (IIS) Manager, on the
>      Directory Security tab of the
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site
>      properties page.
>           5. Click View Certificate.
>           6. On the Certificate dialog box, click Details.
>           7. Click the Friendly Name field to locate the certificate name.
>      If the certificate name is the same as
>      the computer name, you can use the
>      format ServerName:SSLPortNumber. By
>      default, the TCP port for SSL
>      connections is 443.
>           8. In the dbo.DeploymentProperties table, under
>      the ColumnName column, in the
>      ADWebApplicationRootDomain row, change
>      the NVarCharColumn column value by
>      using the name of the certificate
>      configured for the Microsoft Dynamics
>      CRM Web site. If the certificate name
>      is the same as the computer name, you
>      can use the format
>      ServerName:SSLPortNumber. By default,
>      the TCP port for SSL connections is
>      443.
>           9. Make sure your modifications are saved and then close
>      SQL Server Management Studio.
> 5. Modify the LocalSDKPort Windows registry subkey value. To do this,
>      complete the following steps.
>
>    Warning: Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry
>      incorrectly by using Registry Editor
>      or by using another method. These
>      problems might require that you
>      reinstall the operating system and
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM. We cannot
>      guarantee that these problems can be
>      solved. Modify the registry at your
>      own risk.
>           1. Start Registry Editor, and locate the
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM
>      subkey.
>           2. Right-click LocalSdkPort, click Modify, and then click OK.
>           3. In the Base area, click Decimal, and then type the TCP port.
>           4. Click OK.
>           5. Close Registry Editor.
> 6. Restart IIS. To do this, at the command line, run the iisreset
>      command.
> 7. Start the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site. To do this, right-click the
>      Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site, and
>      then click Start.
> 8. Restart the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service.
>      To do this, click Start, point to
>      Administrative Tools, and then click
>      Services. In the list of services,
>      right-click Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>      Asynchronous Processing Service, and
>      then click Restart.
> 9. Verify that you can successfully connect to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>      Web site. To do this, you must use a
>      URL that begins with https. For
>      example, in Internet Explorer the URL
>      will appear similar to the following
>      address:
>      https://ServerName/OrganizationName/loader.aspx
>
>    If the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site is not configured to require
>      SSL connections, verify that you can
>      successfully connect to the site by
>      using an http connection, for example,
>      http://ServerName/OrganizationName/loader.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the SRSS config tool. =>

[Configuring a Report Server for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Connections (2005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(SQL.90).aspx)
[Configuring a Report Server for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Connections (2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223.aspx)

> "Edit UrlRoot in the **RSReportServer.config** File
>   If you are using the report server e-mail delivery extension, you can create subscriptions that included a report URL in the e-mail message. To construct the report URL, the report server uses the UrlRoot configuration setting in the RSReportServer.config file. If the report runs on a report server that is accessed through an SSL connection, you must manually edit the UrlRoot to use the https:// prefix.

If you are using a server certificate, the format of the URL is as follows:

```
<UrlRoot>https://certificatename/reportservervirtualdirectoryname</UrlRoot>
```

Comment: This is good stuff, but the issue isn't that my srs won't work with https - that is all configured.  The issue is that when ms crm passes me the crm_url param it is http and not https.